# Compilation error with C++ (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compilation, g++

I am getting an error when I am trying to compile this very simple C++ program in Mac (HighSierra: Version 10.13.3). The gcc version being used in this Mac is 5.3.0.

This is the C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  cout<<sin(1);
}
```

Following an answer from an earlier question, I installed command line tools using `xcode-select --install`

After the aforementioned command line installation, when I try to compile this program using

```
gcc filename.cpp -o filename.out
```

I get the following error:

```
/var/folders/mp/z7xpkw3538z71904cdqhztv00000gn/T//ccGJEHr7.s:24:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
    .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/mp/z7xpkw3538z71904cdqhztv00000gn/T//ccGJEHr7.s:24:11: note: change section name to "__text"
    .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double)", referenced from:
      _main in ccpjcybF.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccpjcybF.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccpjcybF.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccpjcybF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

**Update:**

Following the answers, now I used `g++`, i.e.

```
g++ filename.cpp -o filename.out
```

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
/var/folders/mp/z7xpkw3538z71904cdqhztv00000gn/T//ccJjEuJy.s:24:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
    .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/mp/z7xpkw3538z71904cdqhztv00000gn/T//ccJjEuJy.s:24:11: note: change section name to "__text"
    .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `g++`:

```
g++ filename.cpp -o filename.out
```

Or Apple's `clang++`:

```
clang++ filename.cpp -o filename.out
```

Answer (score 3):

You are compiling C source code with `gcc`.

That's the problem, you should be using `g++` instead.